# Fit of the l equation

Tags: fitting

I want to find a good fit for my data with the function

```
Exp[a*r^2]*(a + b*x + c*x^3)
```

These are my data.

```
data = {{0.001693, -136.065}, {0.018628, -135.292}, {0.044031, \
-132.778}, {0.074513, -127.169}, {0.086368, -124.46}, {0.096528, \
-121.558}, {0.113463, -115.753}, {0.120237, -114.012}, {0.128704, \
-111.303}, {0.135478, -109.174}, {0.149026, -104.531}, {0.1558, \
-102.0150}, {.162574, -99.8867}, {0.165961, -98.1451}, {0.181202, \
-92.9208}, {0.186283, -91.1793}, {0.199831, -86.5355}, {0.216765, \
-80.15}, {0.22862, -76.6673}, {0.2337, -74.7323}, {0.252329, \
-69.3147}, {0.260796, -66.993}, {0.26757, -64.8646}, {0.27265, \
-63.3167}, {0.291279, -59.0604}, {0.30652, -55.7716}, {0.318374, \
-53.6437}, {0.347163, -49.0013}, {0.367485, -46.6807}, {0.394581, \
-44.3608}, {0.433531, -42.4291}, {0.450466, -41.85}, {0.475868, \
-41.2719}, {0.491109, -40.8862}, {0.528366, -39.7286}, {0.563929, \
-38.3772}, {0.577477, -37.7978}, {0.592718, -36.8316}, {0.623201, \
-34.7055}, {0.638442, -33.3521}, {0.653683, -31.9987}, {0.672312, \
-30.2586}, {0.707875, -26.5846}, {0.724809, -24.8443}, {0.738357, \
-23.1037}, {0.753599, -21.7503}, {0.824725, -14.5959}, {0.834886, \
-13.6292}, {0.865368, -11.116}, {0.882303, -9.56926}, {0.907705, \
-8.02333}, {0.921253, -7.25044}, {0.960203, -5.12518}, {0.987299, \
-4.16006}, {1.00423, -3.58105}, {1.01948, -3.00188}, {1.05673, \
-1.8442}, {1.08552, -1.45989}, {1.116, -1.07574}};
```

Plot of my data.

[image]

Comment: Share a link to that article.

Comment: The code is fine, in that it is syntactically correct and produces no errors. There is no way anyone can know what makes it "unreasonable" for you. You need to give some context.

Comment: sorry, I do not have suggestions, because I do not know what the question posted here is asking. If this is related to other question you have, then may be it will be better if you keep the question posted here in the other question. You could always edit your other question and update it for example.

Comment: I do not believe that the curve to which you have drawn an arrow can be represented by `m + nr + or^3` no matter what the coefficients.  This suggests that you have misinterpreted the article, or that it is incorrect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Comment: I'll edit it soon so please wait  @m_goldberg

Comment: You have two inflexion points and a flat area; no way is a cubic going to be a good fit to your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following provides a good fit but it likely has nothing to do with however the data was generated as I have no idea what subject matter is.  And knowledge of the subject matter should have a strong influence on curve forms to consider.  As such, this should be considered an extended comment rather than an answer.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, -a1 Exp[-(x - b1)^2/σ1^2] - a2 Exp[-(x - b2)^2/σ2^2],
  {a1, a2, b1, b2, σ1, σ2}, x];
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 1.6}]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

Comment: excellent . But this is different from my function .Did you guess the function? How did you find this function? @Jim Baldwin

Comment: It sure is different.  I think your question is likely to close unless you can make a very convincing argument as to why your equation should be the appropriate form for your data.

Comment: +1 for the second sentence. @nasrin: **something** generated your points. There *must* be some sort of **theory** behind these points, which might postulate an appropriate functional form. Concentrate on the theory first before even trying to find something that fits, or you're just doing statistical voodoo otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearModelFit`, i.e.

```
fit = LinearModelFit[data, {r, r^3}, r]
```

Access the parameters `{a,b,c}` through `fit["BestFitParameters"]`.

With the data you provided, I got

```
{a,b,c}=={-121.696, 158.431, -36.0649}
```

Comment: This does not fit me well @terrygarcia

Comment: You'll likely find a better fit if you impose constraints on your parameters. I have no idea what kind of problem you're solving, so I can't help you there. I recommend you look at the documentation.

Comment: Actually, as other commenters have pointed out, a cubic fit does not appear viable.

Comment: Please send me the code that you submitted using fit["BestFitParameters"]. This code gives me an error   @terrygarcia

Comment: `"BestFitParameters"` is a property of `FittedModel` objects returned by `LinearModelFit` and `NonlinearModelFit`. If you've run my code  with your original data, there should be no errors, you just won't have a very good fit. Again, _read the documentation_ on `LinearModelFit`.

Comment: fm = NonlinearModelFit[ data, {(Exp[ar^2]*(-b + cr - d*r^3)), {a, b, c, d}, r].I edited the function.And I got a  good answer. @ J. M.♦